# Prematurely deallocated view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting, nszombie

I am drawing a grid views and experiencing an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error when `UIButton` fires off a selector. Turning on zombie objects gives me the message:

```
*** -[FooViewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x91818f0
```

Here is what I am doing:

```
BazViewController *baz = [[BazViewController alloc] initDesignatedInitializer];
FooViewController *foo = [[FooViewController alloc] initDesignatedInitializer];
[baz.view addSubview:foo.view];
```

I am running this on ARC, so I could see the possibility of FooViewController being prematurely deallocated.

So I did this hack:

Create an `NSMutableArray` ivar&property in BazViewController named `viewControllers` and did this instead:

```
BazViewController *baz = [[BazViewController alloc] initDesignatedInitializer];
FooViewController *foo = [[FooViewController alloc] initDesignatedInitializer];
[baz.view addSubview:foo.view];
[baz.viewControllers addObject:foo];
```

But I still get the same error above.

I proceeded to do the equivalent of the above on the view controller that deals with the grid. (Create a view controllers array, and add the object into it at time of that object's creation). Still no dice. Can anyone recommend a another way to prevent this vc from being prematurely released?

Comment: Your example code is invalid: it uses FooViewController and BazViewController both as type names and variable names. This makes it difficult to tell what's going on: Is the BazViewController being assigned to a local variable? What is responsible for retaining it?

Comment: Code style corrected, I was writing pseudocode though

Comment: In my attempted solution I created a strong mutable array property within the parent view controller and added all the child view controllers in, hoping that this strongly preserved reference would cause ARC to not deallocate their memory prematurely.

Comment: Pseudocode is rarely helpful for figuring out where a missing retain is. What is retaining the parent VC?

Comment: VC hierarchy is UINavigationController > GridViewController > BazViewController > FooViewController; GridViewController is a UIStoryboard scene and it has a strong array property holding all the BazViewControllers, and each BazViewController has an analogous strong array property of FooViewControllers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this issue myself.

Instead of creating arrays I used `addChildViewController` to add a strong reference to the appropriate vc's. No premature deallocation and no zombie objects.

```
BazViewController *baz = [[BazViewController alloc] initDesignatedInitializer];
FooViewController *foo = [[FooViewController alloc] initDesignatedInitializer];
[baz.view addSubview:foo.view];
[baz addChildViewController:foo];
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `FooViewController` property in the class that's creating it and give the property a `strong` attribute.  Assign to that rather than a local variable.

Comment: What if there's a case of 1,2 or 3 `FooViewControllers` inside of the parent view controller? Create properties for all 3 and use them as necessary?